# emacs, python-mode.el define-key map assignment

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, python-mode

When I load the python-mode.el file in emacs, I don't get any of the key bindings specified.
I started playing with the file and noticed that when I change:

```lisp
(define-key map [(control c)(\#)] 'py-comment-region)
```

to:

```lisp
(define-key global-map [(control c)(\#)] 'py-comment-region)
```

it works fine.

I went to look where the define the map variable and saw:

```lisp
(defvar py-shell-map nil
  "Keymap used in *Python* shell buffers.")

;; used by py-completion-at-point, the way of python.el
(defvar python-shell-map
  (let ((map (copy-keymap comint-mode-map)))
    (define-key map [tab]   'py-shell-complete)
    (define-key map "\C-c-" 'py-up-exception)
    (define-key map "\C-c=" 'py-down-exception)
    map)
  "Keymap used in *Python* shell buffers.")
```

Is the 'map' variable defined alright? Should I do some changes to my init file? I assume that this file works to everybody else, so why I need to change the 'map' variable to 'global-map' for it to work in my computer?

I'm running in a virtual machine if that's of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you quoted in which you believe `map` is defined is not actually the relevant portion of the code. It is a different keymap used for a python shell, and it's not the one used when you edit a python file in Emacs.

The line you're editing appears in `python-mode` inside the following code block:

```lisp
(defvar python-mode-map)
(setq python-mode-map
      (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
        ;; electric keys
        (define-key map [(:)] 'py-electric-colon)
        (define-key map [(\#)] 'py-electric-comment)
        ...
```

As you can see the variable `map` is first initialized as a "sparse keymap", then certain key-bindings get defined in that map, and finally the map is set as the value of `python-mode-map`. The latter is the keymap used in a buffer that is in `python-mode`.

So the keybindings should work - but of course only in a buffer that is in `python-mode`. To activate `python-mode` in a buffer, type <kbd>M-x python-mode</kbd>. This works only after the file `python-mode.el` has been loaded.

You can check if your current buffer is in `python-mode` in two ways:

- your mode line should display the letters "Py"
- type <kbd>M-: ENTER major-mode ENTER</kbd> -> this should print "python-mode" to the minibuffer

Comment: Thanks, apparently the loaded env for python remained to be python.el instead of python-mode.el. I added some lines in the init.el to change this, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Each major mode and some minor modes have their own keymap, which is overlaid on the global keymap (which is `global-map`).  When you press a key, Emacs tries to find a binding for that key in the overlaid keymaps, falling back to "more global" ones until it gets to the global-map.  This is why `global-map` works and `map` doesn't.

In lisp, `let` is used to bind local variables.  The `map` variable doesn't exist outside of the `let` (or maybe it does, but it's probably not the one you want).  Read the documentation for `let` and `defvar` (e.g. `C-h f defvar`).

You need to figure out which keymap is being used in the major mode, and use `define-key` on that.  In this case, `(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c #") 'py-comment-region)` will probably work.  N.B. I do not use python-mode.el, but looking at the source it seems like it uses `python-mode-map` as the keymap variable.  The other keymaps are for auxiliary buffers.